# bisect and lists of user defined objects (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmp, bisect

Before python 3, I used bisect to insert user-defined objects into a list.  bisect was happy with this because my user-defined object had a def `__cmp__` that defined how to compare the objects.  I've read the rationale for not supporting cmp in python 3 and I'm fine with that.  I thought a fix for my old code would be to 'decorate' my user-defined object by turning it into a tuple

```
(integer, user-defined object).
```

However, if I have a list of my tuples, and try ...

```
i = bisect_left([list_of_tuples], (integer, user-defined object))
```

then I get an error "builtins.TypeError: unorderable types ..."

So, (in python 3) how do I use bisect for lists of items that aren't made entirely of things with a natural sort order?

Answer (score 18):

You need to add an `__lt__` method; this is now what is used for comparisons instead of `__cmp__`

Comment: P.S. I think you can mark this as the answer to the question which gets me reputation and apparently makes people more likely to answer your future questions.